# python Youtube comment bot. error in scroll and bot dont write comment selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, youtube

I am getting an error with my bot. I need it to scroll to the comments section and write a message in response to the most popular one, but after authorization and going to 1 video the bot finishes its work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

def job():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) 
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False) 
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)  
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending")

    
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier")
    email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "identifierId")))
    email.send_keys("mail")
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "identifierNext").click()

    
    time.sleep(5)

    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='Passwd']")))
    password.send_keys("pas") 
    time.sleep(3) 
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwordNext").click()


    time.sleep(5)

    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending")
 
    video = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ytd-video-renderer:first-child a#thumbnail")))
    video.click()

    # Switch to iframe
    iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,200)")
            
    comment_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "comment")))
    comment_box.send_keys("com") 
            
    time.sleep(2)

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,200)")

    submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "submit-button")))
    submit_button.click()

    # Switch back to the main content
    driver.switch_to.default_content()

job()
```

I don't know how to solve this error. I hope for a quick resolution, thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your post with the error you are getting and make sure to read on ["How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why not using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Comments: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert) endpoint?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: if you get error message then show it in question (not in comments). Don't expect that we will run code to see error. Besides code may work correctly on our computers.